# How make custom status discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Why is my code not working?

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is now working!')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.CustomActivity(name='Custom status' ,emoji='️'))
```

And gives me an error.

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 30, in on_ready
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.CustomActivity(name='Custom status' ,emoji='️'))
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'CustomActivity'
```

How fix is error?

Comment: what version of the discord package are you using?

Comment: I use newest version 1.3.

Comment: Do you have another module, i.e. file or folder, named 'discord' in your path?

Comment: Bots cannot utilize custom statuses, they can only use the previous `Playing`, `Watching` etc.

Comment: You might double check that the version updated correctly, by adding `print(discord.__version__)` to the start of your bot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm late to the party,
WayToDoor is right, bots can't use custom status, I found that they "can use it" but it's invisible except bots can see it's a custom status and you will see "custom status" on the bot profile.

There is Playing, Watching, Listening to, and Streaming available for the bots no problem

You also now have an option to use "Competing in" too, which has type 5. I can't see it on the docs yet so I'm assuming it's not implemented yet.

```py
#this is how "Competing in" is set.
discord.Activity(name="Test", type=5)
```

this should work.

Answer (score 5):

Bots cannot use custom statuses yet. Use `Playing` or `Watching` instead. See https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2400

Comment: Can confirm this is still an ongoing problem.

Comment: There was a time when bots could use custom statuses, with discord.ActivityType.custom, and using state instead of name to define the text.

Answer (score 3):

Great news! Discord has recently added support for bots to use custom statuses, and the code snippet in your question should work just fine!

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is now working!')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.CustomActivity(name='Custom status' ,emoji='️'))
```

But first, make sure you've upgraded your installation of discord.py to version 2.3.2 or higher, using:

```
pip install discord.py>=2.3.2
```

Answer (score 2):

try these:

```py
# Setting `Playing ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="a game"))

# Setting `Streaming ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream", url=my_twitch_url))

# Setting `Listening ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="a song"))

# Setting `Watching ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="a movie"))
```

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def Self_Clock(ctx):
    print("[+]: Status Changer Loaded")
    await ctx.message.delete()
    from datetime import datetime
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': token,
    }
    request = requests.Session()
    while True:
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        setting = {
            'status': "online",
            "custom_status": {"text": f"[+]: My current time: {current_time}"}
        }
        request.patch("https://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/settings",headers=headers, json=setting, timeout=10)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: if it did not why would i add it?