# So Discord bot statuses.....how do I set them?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

So I'd like a status for my discord bot, a "playing" status but not with an actual game, I know you can do that. How do I do that when programming a discord bot in python?

EDIT: I have this code, and it's not working.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio


client = discord.Client()


PREFIX = ("$")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="testing this code"))
    print("Bot is ready!")



client.run(bot_token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To changes a bot's activity you need to use [Client.change_presence](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence)
With its `activity` kwarg, passing any of the following:

- discord.Game
- discord.Streaming (requires a valid twitch URL, not the front page)
- discord.Activity with a valid [ActivityType](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ActivityType) and a `name`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a status as shown in [change_presence](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence)

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("Testing this code"))
    print("Bot is ready!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Setting Playing status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="a game"))

# Setting Streaming status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream", url=my_twitch_url))

# Setting Listening status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="a song"))

# Setting Watching status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="a movie"))
```

(thanks to NOT kar1m yt from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055037/how-make-custom-status-discord-py) post who I copied this from :) )